# Server returned 503 VsCode extension marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Extension marketplace is returning this when trying to search for extension
`Error while fetching extensions. Server Returned 503`

here is information about VsCode:

```bash
Version: 1.69.2
Commit: 3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a
Date: 2022-07-19T13:15:38.080Z (3 days ago)
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.18.12-arch1-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in the following way:

1. Change your router and device DNS to CloudFlare/Google from whatever you are using specifically, assuming it is the ISP's one.
2. Restart your network service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
   ```
3. Flush your DNS cache:

   ```
   sudo resolvectl flush-caches
   ```

4: Restart your PC

…and voila! It worked for me this way.

Comment: my pleasure hopefully it won't come back.